# Basic web service calling in android

Tags: android, web-services

I need a tutorial on how to do a basic web service call in android. I currently use ksoap but I and getting an error when I make the call and I need to know what the response from the server was. ksoap wont give me that information because it parses the response in the api where I am getting the error.

I am new to all this web service stuff so please help me out

Comment: i recommend this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends what you want to develop it using

A good tutorial using PHP, MySQL is [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)

I know you are using KSOAP at the moment but here is a [nice tutorial](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html) that uses KSOAP and in explained in nice detail.